# Preprocessor macro to remove code if compiled after a certain date

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor

I would like three lines of code not to be included if compiled after a certain date.
The reason being is they provide backwards compatibility. To support a staggered release between client and embedding it is required to be there now.

Once the next software release comes along this support is to be dropped to force customers to upgrade the embedded software. Since this is a few months away there is risk of these lines being forgotten.

So ideally I would like a

```
#if __DATE__ > MyDate
    code here
#endif
```

or something equivalent.
Is there any way of doing this?

*The code is compiled with GCC

Answer (score 5):

This solution is specifically for Windows platform and is something I use in production.

I exploit the environment variable %DATE%, and in a batch file used to launch my IDE, I have  VA_CURRENT_DATE=%DATE:~6,4%%DATE:~3,2%%DATE:~0,2% (which transforms to an ISO8601 date for my specific locale).

Then in my preprocessor definitions for my project I define VA_BUILD_DATE to VA_CURRENT_DATE

Then I have some code like:

```
long day = VA_BUILD_DATE;
long year = day / 10000;
day -= year * 10000;
long month = day / 100;
day -= month * 100;
```

Comment: Not applicable to my environment i'm afraid but its a good thing to know. Thanks

Comment: In a Unixy makefile, `-DBUILD_DATE="$$(date +%Y%m%d)L"` would be a rough equivalent, I think.  'Ware quoting headaches.

Comment: By using a macro name beginning with an underscore followed by a capital letter like `_VA_BUILD_DATE` you invoke undefined behavior, because such names are reserved according to the standard (see C99 draft standard, section 7.1.3).

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this with `__DATE__`, because it expands to a string constant, and string constants can't be used in `#if`.  Also, setting a fixed date is a bad idea, because you may need to do bug-fix releases to the older version that should preserve the backward compatibility.

(Do you really *need* to drop backward compatibility?  If it's only three lines of code, consider just keeping them around forever.  Your customers will not thank you for "forcing them to upgrade.")

The good way to do this sort of thing is via your version control system.  You should be maintaining a branch for each release anyway, so write your code like this:

```
#ifdef BACKWARD_COMPAT_VERSION_1_0
    compatibility code here
#endif
```

and then change the Makefile on the release branch, only, to include `-DBACKWARD_COMPAT_VERSION_1_0` in your CFLAGS.

Comment: The reason for dropping the compatibility is other things really aren't going to work. By removing these lines it breaks things in a safe and early way.
The version control way seems a sensible approach. I would still rather it be date based, but if nobody can suggest a way to do this I shall attempt that.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Now I am running the risk of not answering your question directly. But I'd take the risk and suggest you NOT to do so. How many times does a project get released on time? The date is, too prone to change. And you never know that.

Why not use the version of your project instead?

```
// Only defined in old projects that you want this legacy code in.
#ifdef OLD__VERSION
    code here
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this won't work as `__DATE__` produces a string in the form `"Sep  5 2013"`, which is useless for comparison.

Ideally the compiler should support a constant like `__DATEFLAT__` which produces an integer like `20130905`, which would be ideal for such as task.  However this doesn't exist.